# Count row in filtered table

Tags: javascript, html

I can count the total of rows in my table with the code bellow.
How can I count the number of rows displayed when I apply a filter?

```
  var x = document.getElementById("userTbl").rows.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x + " rows in the table.";
}
```

Comment: Could you provided more info about your issue
Maybe deploy the code to codepen or a similer platform

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function again as soon as the filter is applied.